# Removing Images from CustomAdapter

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter

I have a custom ImageAdapter that wraps item for a GridView in my activity.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
public ArrayList<Integer>  mThumbIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Integer> mThumbIds) {
mContext = c;
this.mThumbIds = mThumbIds;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.size();
}    
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              ImageView imageView;
              if (convertView == null) {
                  imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                  imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                  imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                  } else {
                  imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
              }

              imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds.get(position));
              return imageView;
  }


public void modifyData (ArrayList<Integer> newData){
    getmThumbIds().clear();
    for (Integer var : newData){
        getmThumbIds().add(var);
        }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This adapter is created in my main Activity and associated to the GridView.

```
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, getIdIngredients());
    grilleImagesIngredients = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grilleImagesIngredients);
    grilleImagesIngredients.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Finally I just want to erase all the images from my grid view, so:

```
imageAdapter.mThumbIds.clear();
imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This method is working fine when I add objects. With some empirical tests I' ve seen that it's not removing the previous images in the grid, just drawing the new one over it.

Once I removed the objects from the adapter, they're no longer selectable in the gridView, but I still see the images.

Comment: what's getmThumbIds() ?

Comment: Just a getter : 
     public ArrayList<Integer> getmThumbIds() {
  return mThumbIds;
 }

Comment: By calling `getIdIngredients().clear()`, what do you actually clear?

Comment: I edited that, I just mis-copypaste.

Comment: Try to call adapter.modifyData(new ArrayList<Integer>()) to clear the grid.

Comment: I did, with the same result unfortunately.

Comment: For some reasons that go beyond my understanding, I changed the style from FullScreen to AppBaseTheme and it's now working fine.